# swagger error for my upgraded .netcore app

Tags: .net-core, swagger, nswag

So I do have this web api built in .netcore 2.2 when Im on the process of upgrading this error shows up

System.InvalidOperationException: 'API Explorer not registered in DI.'

I already upgraded my swagger nugget and follow some instructions in upgrading but this error still pops up.

[Click for the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OREjL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `services.AddMvcCore().AddApiExplorer();`

in `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`